# Auto Submit form After Finished Fill Text Box & also check data from database using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, database, submit

Auto Submit form After Finished Fill Text Box & also check data from database using ajax

[image]

Comment: give a timeout combined with keyup event to achieve ajax the form submision for complete event, check this [plugin](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/)

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is your problem?